# Testcontainers for .NET does not indicate container creation

Tags: c#, docker, .net-6.0, testcontainers

I have a simple xUnit.net integration test using Testcontainers NuGet package in version `2.3.0` to run a Microsoft SQL Server instance in a Docker container.

The test looks like this:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task TestDatabaseConnection()
{
    var container = new TestcontainersBuilder<MsSqlTestcontainer>()
        .WithDatabase(new MsSqlTestcontainerConfiguration
        {
            Password = "password",
        })
        .Build();
    await container.StartAsync();

    using var connection = new SqlConnection(container.ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    connection.State.Should().Be(System.Data.ConnectionState.Open);
}
```

However, `container.StartAsync()` throws `DockerAPIException`:

```
Docker.DotNet.DockerApiException : Docker API responded with status code=Conflict, response={"message":"Container 7b487d4475ece5c37e24f553a2f9d9c133a37636025b8731b22dea5022c628ca is not running"}
```

In Docker Desktop I see the container with the exact same Id as in the exception, and at the end of the test the container gets removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright my bad. The password [requirements](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) were the problem:

> A strong system administrator (SA) password: At least 8 characters including uppercase, lowercase letters, base-10 digits and/or non-alphanumeric symbols.